# MySQL database on EC2

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-ec2

I am new to Django, MySQL, and EC2. I am trying to develop a small scale app and just had  acouple questions as I got started. I have read through the Django tutorial and want to get started trying some of the stuff I just learned out.

One thing I am having trouble with is how do I create a MySQL database on EC2?

I have installed the following things on my EC2 instance so far:

- Django 1.3
- MySQL
- Apache
- mysql_server
- MySQL-python

Is there something I ahve ot download in addition or is there a command I can use to create start creating databases and tables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you are not using RDS, then it's just a regular MySQL instance. Look up mysql administration tutorials on google. At the very least you can use the `mysql` command-line tool.

Comment: And if you want to connect to the database externally, you may have to add a firewall opening for the port that MySQL operates on (`3306` unless you changed it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind installing PHP in your server, then phpmyadmin is an excellent, free, tool. It allows you to manage your database in a very intuitive way. I strongly recommend it if you are new to MySQL.

If PHP is not an option, then you can either look for a non-PHP graphic tool as an alternative to phpmyadmin, or use the mysql shell command:

```
$ mysql -u username -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;
mysql> USE mydatabase;
mysql> CREATE TABLE ... ... ...
```